# How to apply a .NET .config file to a running process?

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a .NET assembly (.dll) that gets loaded as a COM server into an existing process.  How can I get a .config file applied to it such that `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` will return  the section out of the applied .config file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx). There's good code samples in the link, so I won't copy them here.

Comment: That just opens up a read/write copy of the .config file for authoring.  It doesn't actually apply the .config file to the process such that ConfigurationManager.AppSettings or GetSection reads from that file.

Comment: Nope - it actually forces the application to use the new configuration file. Notice the section near the bottom of the example, where RefreshSection() is called after the changes are made - it's illustrating explicitly that the ConfigurationManager is now pulling data from the mapped configuration file.